# MVC and separate projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, project

I am new to MVC. I'd like to have my data objects in a separate project from my main MVC project. Would I just move ALL the classes and files from my 'models' folder to my new all project, and then add a reference to the new data project in my MVC project? How would I then make used of the models, both in my controllers (still in the MVC project) as well as within my views?

Comment: Mh, can you be a bit more specific about programming-language used, framework used and so on?It helps to imagine what you want.


As your question says I think you can "simply" create everything in this order (I mean, instancing):

-Model (doesn't require anything)

-View (require a model)

-Controller (require model and view)

Doing this is easy, I mean you can just set a pointer to models and views in the constructor

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I (incorrectly) assumed MVC was a Microsoft thing. Sorry about that. I am using .net (4.0) in visual studio 2010, with C#.

Comment: MVC is a design pattern, a coding paradigm. ASP.NET MVC is a toolset Microsoft provides to accomplish it. Updated your tag for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going in the right direction. In fact, for all but the most trivial projects, I like to have my model in a separate class library. And then, as you mentioned, you can reference the class library from your MVC project and use your model classes. The benefit being once you have your model ready and polished in a class library, you can "expose" to any kind presentation layer such as your MVC project or Windows Phone 7 or expose through WCF.

Keep in mind though that repositories are NOT part of your model. They are a persistence concern and they should only do the CRUD operations, plain and simple. Any kind of manipulation should go in the models layer.

Answer (score 0):

You would create libraries with the tools appropriate to your implementation technology.  For example, with Java you would create jar(s) containing the models.  You would put the jars on the classpath of whichever project(s) used them; once you do that you have access to the library.

This is a good (great) idea if you want to reuse the model objects and business requirements they implement in more than one place.  Perhaps you want customers to use your model API to implement their own sorts of clients, for example.

You could maintain the model layer as its own project, or keep it in the 'main' project and have build processes to produce the desired artifacts.  You haven't given us enough information to give a hard answer on what the best approach is.

I can say this: most projects start with all the layers within the one project.  If a part of the project becomes significantly complex, you can refactor out separate projects--On some projects I have seen, the web client is sufficiently complex to be its own project with its own development team (and its own MVC layers).  On other projects, the entire MVC stacks were all in one project.  Note that you do not need the M in MVC to be in a separate project to follow the paradigm.  You just need to handle all the concerns in the correct layer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just making a really small learning project. So in real life, I'd keep it as one. However, I'd like to convert an older web app to MVC. And that has 2 interfaces. Winforms and the web app. I currently use a classic asp.net web service, which has the bl and dl. That will be converted to entity framework as the data layer, and then have the web service reference the ef project. Not sure actually. I'd then probably have to have a shared class lib, with the data objects. Actually. I need to think about this.